# How to use collision?

Tags: animation, physics, collision

Hey this is the first time trying to use collision and I have no idea how to use/activate it for an animation.

Also I tried finding it online but had no luck.

Comment: Right click to select an object, go to the physics panel, and then click enable physics for Collision.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on what it is you are wanting to do. From your question I get the impression you want to do rigid body phyiscs. Collision is meant for particles, soft bodies and cloth simulations.  To give an object collision properties select it and then click the physics tab inside the properties window, the tab looks like a bouncing ball.  Then click collisions. That object now has collisions.

If you wanted rigid objects to do physics simulations, then the physics button under the physics tab is what you want. A specific answerable question is needed for additional information.

Here is a good tutorial from BlenderGuru that gives a similar type problem. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9L8qOq1Shiw
Main difference is you could just make the bullet so it does not render, and you will have blocks just exploding.

Below you can see I have created a bunch of blocks.
[image: BlockSetup]
  To them the rigid body modifier has been applied.  In the lower right hand corner of the image I have checked two bosex "Enable Deactivation" and "Start Deactivation".  This means they will not move until something acts upon them.

Then create another object and also click the rigid body button for it.  Under the physics tab the rigid body options is an option for mass, make this object much larger than the mass of all the objects you wish to have "explode".

See below:
[image: ProjectileSetup]

This object has had the "Animated" checkbox selected under the physics tab.  I then set key frames for it so it would start below the blocks and then something like 20 frames later it will be far above the blocks.  When play is pushed it will crash through the blocks.  Make sure the projectile's render option is deselected and the blocks will simply explode.

You could also replace or enhance the explosion by using force fields.  In the 3d tab use shift+A and add a force field.  You can key frame the strength of the force fields in the physics tab so they are initially zero and then ramp up to whatever number you want.

Comment: Hey what im trying to do is like a force below a few blocks and explodes upwards and it moves the blocks. I cant really explain it in words but if you watch this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hESDR2yLUD4&t=570s    and skip to 8:57 thats what im trying to do